# How do magic characters scale their basic attacks?

Tags: smite

When playing as magical-based characters, you can't buy items that increase your physical power. Physical power directly influences the damage of your basic attacks. Do magic users like Athena or Anubis gain any benefit to their basic attack by stacking Magical Power?

If not, is there some other way to power up their basic attacks? If so, is there some kind of scaling factor, since Magical Power comes in much higher quantities than Physical Power?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The damage scaling for magical characters (mages and guardians) is 20% of their magical power. Physical gods get 100% scaling.

the formula is:  (Base Damage + (Base Damage per lvl × God's lvl)) + (100% of Physical Power OR 20% of Magical Power)

so as an example. Anubis's base damage at lvl 1 is 35 and every level he gains 1.5. If he got 100 magical power, the formula becomes (35+(1.5*1)) + (100*.2)) = 56.5.

Anubis will deal 56 damage to the enemy if they have 0 protections.

**Yes**, building magical power is not only good for your skills, but your basic attacks as well.

[source and more info here](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Damage)

I missed the part of your question about enhancing basic attacks. Yes there are a handful of items that give you an extra oomf on your basic attack. they are:

- [Telkhines Ring](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Telkhines_Ring) gives extra 40 magical damage for each basic attack (so it just adds 40 to that formula above)
- [Polynomicon](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Polynomicon) after using an ability, you gain an extra 50% magical power damage on your next basic attack.

Comment: I'd edit this in, but reviewers like rejecting edits that change the content "too much". Rod of Tahuti needs an explicit mention here as well. While not in the item's text, it does behind the scenes explicitly increase your basic attack damage by another 25%. http://smite.gamepedia.com/Rod_of_Tahuti